# python installing Google App Engine through pip

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I tried to follow [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123553/how-to-install-google-appengine) and install Google App Engine module for python using pip. This seems cleaner for me than downloading raw files and adding PATH export to bashrc.

So I tried:

```
tomasz@tomasz-lenovo-ideapad-Y530:~$ sudo pip install appengine.py
[sudo] password for tomasz: 
Downloading/unpacking appengine.py
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement appengine.py
No distributions at all found for appengine.py
Storing complete log in /home/tomasz/.pip/pip.log
```

and it failed. I don't know what's wrong, because the `appengine` module is available: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appengine. Can anyone point me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without the .py? `pip install appengine`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
    sudo pip install appengine
```

instead. Basically, don't add the .py at the end.